# Merant Tracker - move query items to In Tray

Tags: database, tracker

I'm writing a Tracker to JIRA application moving issues from the Tracker database to JIRA database. The app processes issues from the Tracker In Tray and places them in JIRA. If I do a query on the issues I wish to move (state, status, etc) how do I move those query issues to the In Tray? I know I've done this before but I can not figure out how or what I did. This is all done manually, not via the app. The app processes the In Tray later.

Update:
I have tried this but nothing is moving. Do query, select issues, select "Notify User", select myself and check the "In Tray" checkbox but nothing is moving.

Thanks in advance
T

Answer (score 0):

Found that when I logged off and back in the In Tray has been updated. Thanks for listening.